# OpenGL - Switching from C to C++

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm learning to write OpenGL programs. So far, I've been using C, but I'm realizing as the programs get more involved, it might be nice to program in a more object oriented way, so I'm setting up a skeleton program in C++.

This program couldn't be any simpler. Except that I get this error:

`No matching function for call to glutInit()`

I've seen this error in other posts, and I've implemented the suggestions, but the error remains. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

chess.h

```
#ifndef __chess1__chess1__
#define __chess1__chess1__

#include <iostream>
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>    //edited
#endif /* defined(__chess1__chess1__) */
```

chess.cpp

```
#include "chess.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    glutInit();
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 1000);
    glutCreateWindow("Chess Program");
    glutMainLoop();
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: What's `#import`? Also, why is your header not `#include`d in your `.cpp`?

Comment: If you haven't, you'll want to `#include "chess.h"` in chess.cpp, too.

Comment: `__chess__chess__` is also a reserved identifier that you should not be using.

Comment: Sorry, @BrainSteel, forgot to paste that line in. @us2012, thanks - I changed that to `#include`. Still have the same error, though.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths - I didn't know that. Xcode put that there, so I'm surprised. I changed it to chess1 to be safe. Same error persists.

Comment: `glutInit()` takes two parameters. That could be confusing the compiler. http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node10.html It's `glutInit(int* argcp, char** argv)`.

Comment: @usr55410: *any* identifier with a double underscore in it is reserved.

Comment: @BrainSteel - that was it. If you post this an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: No problemo, man. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glutInit(int* argcp, char** argv)` takes two parameters, one being a pointer to argc and the other being argv. It should be called as such: `glutInit(&argc, argv)`.

http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node10.html